# Python module export Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I relatively new to Python but my understanding of Python modules is that any object defined in a module can be exported, for example is you had:

```py
# my_module.py
obj1 = 4
obj2 = 8
```

you can import both these objects simply with `from my_module import obj1, obj2`.

While working with Pandas, it is common to have code with looks like this (not actual working code):

```py
# pandas_module.py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df = df.drop()
df = df[df.col > 0]
```

where the same object (`df`) is redefined multiple times. If I want to export `df` how should I handle this? My guess is that if I simply `from pandas_module import df` from elsewhere, all the pandas code will run first and I will the the final df as expected, but I'm not sure if this is good practice. Maybe it is better to do something like `final_df = df.copy()` and export `final_df` instead. This seems like it would be more understandable for someone who is not that familiar with Python.

So my question is, what is the proper way to handle this situation of exporting a `df` which is defined multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I usually create a function that returns a Dataframe object. Such as:

```
# pandas_module.py
import pandas as pd

def clean_data():

    df = pd.DataFrame(...)
    df = df.drop()
    df = df[df.col > 0]

    return df
```

Then you can call the function from your main work flow and get the expected Dataframe:

```
from pandas_module.py import clean_data

df = clean_data()
```